# How can I get the exact HTML (after the JS functions are executed) using HtmlPage Object?

Tags: htmlunit, browser-automation

I am using Htmlunit (browser automation/testing tool) to get a webpage from a URL, add value to certain HTML elements like textinput, etc and then I want to automate the "click operation using the statement:

```
`HtmlPage page2 = button.click();`
```

and then I want to display the response on default browser. But. the HTML I request for (from URL) is RAW  HTML with javascript functions, which when executed, call some webservices, only after which the exact HTML(one which is rendered on the browser) is generated.
Hence, I wanted to know how I can execute these JS functions in my java program, so that I can get the proper HTML elements, I'm looking for..
Here is my code:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
// Get the first page
final HtmlPage page1 = (HtmlPage)webClient.getPage("http://some URL");
```

HtmlPage Object page1 has raw JS functions..
Thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebWindowListener:

```
    WebWindowListener listener = new WebWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void webWindowOpened(WebWindowEvent event) {
            Page newPage = event.getNewPage();
        }

        @Override
        public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent event)
        {
            Page generatedPage = event.getNewPage();
        }
    }

    webClient.addWebWindowListener(listener);
```